# How to Allow User Access to Published App Maker App?

Tags: google-app-maker

I've built an app in App Maker and deployed it, but the user I thought I had given permission to is getting this notification "Sorry, you don't have access to this application."

In the app, I added a role to the data source and added the user to the role from the deployment. I also added the role to each page's security. I verified that App Maker is turned on for all of our users. I've ensured that the user has access to the Google Sheet data tables (both what I imported into the App for preview and the data I exported from the deployment). I've even added the user as a Cloud Sql Viewer in our Cloud SQL instance (don't know if that was necessary). This is my first app and I feel like I'm flying blind. I'm obviously missing something but can't figure out what. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure **all** the required models can be accessed by the role you assigned to the user.
2. If the user has another Google account in the same Chrome session, the browser may be switching them to this external user when opening the app. Sign-out from that account or try incognito.
3. Make sure the deployment has no restriction as shown here; or if it does, allow the username.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help, AlexZB! I had overlooked the first place I had to list the user as having access. Once added there, it fixed the issue.